# Pass between components data on page load vue2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I know there is possibility to pass data through emit or props but is any possibility to pass data between two "sibling" components when page is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well the question. You can create a global bus for you need and this is quite easy with `vue-js`. You can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arvidkahl/gxdn6ycv/17/) as well.

#### EventBus

Create a file `event-bus.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

#### Component A

To send data you would do

```
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';
EventBus.$emit('my-event', this.data);
```

#### Component B

To receive data in your other component you would do

```
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';
EventBus.$on('my-event', data=> {
  console.log(`${data}`)
});
```

Comment: I will sure take a look, anyways ,it worked so thanks a lot :)